# Deploy React.js project to AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, mern

I am trying to deploy my react.js project to AWS ec2. My teacher told us to use Nginx, so I ran this command

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm nginx git -y
```

I successfully clone my code to the server, and able to browse nginx page by navigating to my public IP address.

I also successfully clone my repository, export variable on the server.

The issue occur while setting up the front-end. In terminal, I cd into my client folder

```
cd ~/$repoName
npm i

cd client
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html
sudo mv build /var/www/html
```

remove the original nginx page, and then create my front page, it gives me error message

> mv: cannot stat 'build': No such file or directory

On my public web page reflects 404 Not Found instead of original welcome nginx page.

Comment: Can you check if you actually have a build directory there inside client/ ? Based on the error, it's not there.

Comment: Dd you actually build the code, or just clone it?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use npm to build your react project and then copy all the files to your server.

Comment: Ok, move all the files from the build to /var/www/html/

Comment: how can I find the build

Comment: In the directory where you have your React project use this __npm build__ this will create the folder **build** and inside it you will find all the code you have to put into /var/www/html/